# Why are newly registered users disabled (django, userena)?

Tags: python, django

When I go to the signup form provided by userena I can successfully register a new user. I can verify this by going to my site/admin page and seeing the new profile listed.

The problem is when I try to sign in the new user, I get a page that says "This account has been disabled."

Things I've tried:

1. Deleted my database
2. python manage.py syncdb
3. python manage.py migrate
4. python manage.py check_permissions

Yet this process yields the same problem.

Another problem which might be related is that my superuser (created when I first ran syncdb) has a functioning profile which I can sign into. But when I go to edit the profile, none of the edited fields get saved.

Any thoughts? Any addition information that I can provide that might be helpful?

**Update:**

Skimming through my database I found a field in the auth_user table called is_active. Apparently this is how userena (or django; not sure which is populating what tables) is determining whether a user is usable or not. When the user is created the default value is zero (disabled). By changing the value to 1 for the newly created user, signin is now possible (no longer disabled). My task is now to determine how to change the default of this value to 1 upon signup. I will post an update when I find it, or please point me in the right direction. (As a side note, this did not help with the problem of being able to edit a profile.)

**Update:**

I found a solution for allowing sign-in of new users, but I am still having trouble getting profile information to save. I created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095027/userena-how-can-i-get-the-fields-in-edit-profile-to-save-strange-behavior) for this issue.

Comment: My guess is it has something to do with userena. See: https://django-userena.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html?highlight=activation

Comment: I went through the settings and nothing seemed to stick out. I tried removing the email activation but that didn't help either.

Comment: is `USERENA_ACTIVATION_REQUIRED` set to False?

Comment: @Thomas yes, that is indeed what I was suggesting in my last comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I traced the methods used during signup and found that I was referencing the wrong settings.py file in forms.py and managers.py. This kept userena from seeing the change I made to `USERENA_ACTIVATION_REQUIRED`. I updated the import statements and this fixed my problem. Newly created users are now active immediately upon registration and can sign in.

**Summary:**

1. Set `USERENA_ACTIVATION_REQUIRED` in settings.py to `False`
2. Ensure that the correct settings.py file is imported in forms.py and managers.py

Changed settings.py from:

```
from userena import settings as userena_settings
```

To:

```
from apps.userena import settings as userena_settings
```

Note that this is my case because I chose to manually install userena on my `PYTHON_PATH` rather than installing automatically with `pip`.