# Userena: How can I get the fields in "edit profile" to save

Tags: python, django

I have a user I have successfully registered in userena. When I view the profile, the information entered in during signup is properly displayed. I click "edit profile" and am presented with the form. I then noticed this behavior:

1. View profile (data is correct)
2. Edit profile then click save (redirected to the same form with all information still filled in)
3. View profile (newly saved information is gone)
4. Edit profile and only fill in the "favorite snack" field (redirected to the "view profile" page with the "favorite snack" now showing)
5. The profile now behaves normally and can be edited and saved like normal.

Why is the proper functioning of the edit profile page dependent on whether I have the "favorite snack" field filled in? Note that "favorite snack" is defined in models.py as outlined in the [userena tutorial](http://docs.django-userena.org/en/latest/installation.html?highlight=favourite_snack).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It looks like I can allow for a blank field with the following change.

**Old Code:**

```
favourite_snack = models.CharField(_('favourite snack'),
                                   max_length=5)
```

**New Code:**

```
favourite_snack = models.CharField(_('favourite snack'),
                                   max_length=5, blank=True)
```